# Spring retry strategy on a boolean flag

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-retry

We are planning to use spring retry feature and want to retry on a boolean flag rather than an exception. When we use the `SimpleRetryPolicy`, the retry seems to be happening only on an exception. Can we tweak it or use a different retry policy where in we can check for a boolean flag instead?

Thanks

Comment: What if you check if boolean flag is set and then throw a specific Exception?

Comment: I thought exactly the same but we are also trying to send back some data on both success and failure and I don't like it that I can send it back only on a success. I can store the data as an instance variable before I throw the exception but don't really like that. Any suggestions?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to achieve `RetryTempate` is fully based on the `while (canRetry(retryPolicy, context) ` and ` catch (Throwable e) {` inside that `while`... You can add some variable to the `RetryContext` through the `RetrySynchronizationManager` but I'm not sure how to achieve `canRetry()` if there is no exception...